# Docker compose volume definition using environment variable

Tags: docker, milvus

I'm running a containerized Milvus Standalone database ([Milvus](https://milvus.io/)) and I'm trying to find the location of items added to the database. In the docker-compose.yml file, the volume location is defined as follows:

```
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKER_VOLUME_DIRECTORY:-.}/volumes/etcd:/etcd
```

Checking my docker server, I do not find an environment variable named DOCKER_VOLUME_DIRECTORY.
What does this definition mean? Also, what does the

```
:-.
```

part mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is using [Shell Parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
${parameter:-word}
```

If `parameter` is unset or null, then `word` is used as a default value.

In this case, as `DOCKER_VOLUME_DIRECTORY` is not set, the default value of `.` (the current directory) is used.

```
$ echo ${DOCKER_VOLUME_DIRECTORY:-.}
.
```

So the volume will effectively be:

```
volumes:
  - ./volumes/etcd:/etcd
```

Comment: Note that Compose only [supports](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution) a limited set of shell parameter expansions.  So `${VARIABLE:-default}` works, but not _e.g._ `${VARIABLE+alternative value}`.